# How to align the label on top of the input field component in the Salesforce LWC?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I need help to align the label on top of the input field. Please see the reference in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, labels are aligned on top of the inputs.

```
<lightning-input label="First Name" value={firstName} name="firstName">
</lightning-input>
```